How to prove that the following scheme is not necessarily CCA-secure if instantiated with a MAC that is not strongly secure?
The following question is from the third edition of Katz's and Lindell's book Introduction to Modern Cryptography. My strategy was to find an attack to the construction in the given conditions, but I'm not satisfied with my current answer.
How do I prove that the following scheme is not necessarily CCA-secure if it is instantiated with a secure MAC that is not strongly secure?
Let ΠE = (Enc, Dec) be a private-key encryption scheme and let ΠM = (Mac, Vrfy) be a message authentication code, where in each case
key generation is done by simply choosing a uniform n-bit key. Define a private-key encryption scheme (Gen', Enc', Dec') as follows:
Gen': on input 1n, choose independent, uniform kE, kM $\in$ {0, 1}n and output the key (kE, kM).
Enc': on int a key (kE, kM) and a plaintext message m, compute c $\leftarrow$ EnckE(m) and t $\leftarrow$ MackM(c). Output the ciphertext [c, t].
Dec': on input a key (kE, kM) and a ciphertext [c, t], first check if VrfykM(c, t) == 1. If yes, output DeckE(c; if no, output $\bot$.

Can you share your current answer so we know where to help?

The main difference between strongly secure MAC and non-strongly secure MAC: A non-strongly-secure-mac-adversary may forge a different tag $t_2\ne t_1$ on the same message $m$, with $\mathsf{ver}(m,t_1)=\mathsf{ver}(m,t_2)=1$.
Therefore, given a plain-ciphertext pair $(m,(c,t))$ via the encryption oracle, the CCA-adversary can forge a new tag $t'\ne t$ with $\mathsf{ver}(m,t')=1$. Obviously $(m,(c,t'))$ is a valid challange since $ t\ne t'\Rightarrow(m,(c,t))\ne(m,(c,t'))$.
I hope this may help :)

Thank you @HaotianYin! I got to the same answer, but wasn't satisfied because I wasn't sure if just changing the tag would make the ciphertext valid to query the oracle with it. But it makes sense, since the ciphertext is composed by the encrypted message together with the tag.

@pedropiin It may look trivial since I can hardly imagine a practical attack scenario or intuitive attack strategy is represented by this attack. The most important part - ciphertext is the same XD

that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!
